# Mysterious added div border

Tags: html

I want a nav bar with the green background filling 100% the screen width, and the texts and logo are located at the center of the nav bar.

This is my html and css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #e9eaed;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #93bf2e;  
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
  
}

#navMain {
    width: 1096px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;   
    
}

#navLeft {
    width: 431px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;    
    display:inline-block;
    
}

#navRight {
    width: 431px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 0; 
    text-align: right;  
    display:inline-block;    
}



#navCenter {
    width:146px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;     
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Homepage.css">
        <title>Home</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>            
            <div id="navMain">
                <div id="navLeft">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Page</div>
                <div id="navCenter"><img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png"></div>
                <div id="navRight">Create Story&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</div>                
            </div>
        </nav>             
    </body>
</html>
```

I use `Display:inline-block` to keep 3 DIVs in the same line. The center div width is 146. The center div contains a 146px-width image. But the problem is I set the width of the main DIV which contains 3 other DIVs to 1096. If I set the left (with left padding 40px) and right (with right padding 40px) DIVs width to 435 the right Div is pushed to the second line. This is weird because the math is right (435 + 40 + 435 + 40 + 146). But if I set the width of left and right DIVs to 431, they are in the same line. This means 8 pixels are mysteriously lost to div borders in some way. Would you please help to remove those borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get these spaces between your `div`s is because you have spaces between the elements in your code (e.g. line break and tabs or spaces). Remove them from your markup and the `div`s will be lined up correctly:

```
<div id="navMain">
  <div id="navLeft">Home    My Page</div><div id="navCenter"><img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png"></div><div id="navRight">Create Story    Log Out</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use HTML comments:

```
<div id="navMain">
  <div id="navLeft">Home    My Page</div><!--
  --><div id="navCenter">
    <img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png">
  </div><!--
  --><div id="navRight">Create Story    Log Out</div>
</div>
```

Looks ugly, but does the trick. Hope this helps, now that you know the reason why your layout does not look as expected. I'd rework the entire structure though, because `inline-block` seems unsuitable here.

Also have a look at [this page](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for further information and alternative solutions.

Comment: I try your HTML comments suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept an answer, if it solved your problem (click checkmark next to it).

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're using `display: inline-block` for the element, which will create a space between each element if you separate the element with a space / new line / tab, what you need to do to overcome this is by not separating the element with a space / new line / tab, or give a comment for the space, or set a negative margin, you can read more way to do it from this [site](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Here's an example with your code: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/y8zfbc4s/)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #e9eaed;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #93bf2e;  
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  
  
}

#navMain {
    width: 1096px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;   
    
}

#navLeft {
    width: 435px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;    
    display:inline-block;
    
}

#navRight {
    width: 435px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 0; 
    text-align: right;  
    display:inline-block;    
}



#navCenter {
    width:146px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;     
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="navMain">
        <div id="navLeft">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Page</div>
        <div id="navCenter">
            <img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="navRight">Create Story&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</div>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav>
    <div id="navMain"><div id="navLeft">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Page</div><div id="navCenter"><img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png"/></div><div id="navRight">Create Story&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</div></div>
</nav>

<nav>
    <div id="navMain">
        <div id="navLeft">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Page</div><!--
        --><div id="navCenter"><!--
            --><img src="../GeneralImages/logo.png"/><!--
        --></div><!--
        --><div id="navRight">Create Story&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</div><!--
    --></div>
</nav>
```